# How can I upload videos to Bunny through GCP?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, bunnycdn

I developing an app, where users can upload videos and stream it.

The app is flutter, base on firebase, I use Google products (firebase auth, firestore database, cloud functions.)

Earlier I use firebase storage for store videos and images, I used google transcoder API in cloud functions for make hls videos, but when I want to stream it's very large price 0,12$/GB. On Bunny.net it's only 0,005$/GB. So I rethinking, I want to store videos on Bunny.net.

But, how?

I think HTTP request not too safe, because then I need to store Bunny API key in my app and need to send it from client. I think it's not safe.

Need proxy server? Which google cloud platform product can use for this? I think need something on server side, where can I transfer data from client side through google server to Bunny server.

Other possible solution maybe I can send files to cloud functions and cloud functions upload file to bunny, but maybe it will be very long runtime and maybe very expensive. (Maybe more expensiver than I use firebase storage...)

Info: My users maybe want to upload files up to 5 GB.

I don't know all google products, if you know good solution for this, how can I upload safely videos or other files to Bunny, please help me. Thanks :)